# user and group account

Tags: macos

I created a new admin account after I lost access privilege to the one I had, the issue is that now there's two accounts ie standard account with all my data and the new admin account with literary nothing. I want to delete the standard account and remain with the admin account only but am afraid to lose my data on the standard account, i need help before I mess up.

Comment: How did you lose  access privilege?

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to reassign admin rights to the standard user.

- Log out of the standard user account
- Log into the admin account
- Open System Preferences -> Users & Groups
- Select the standard user
- Tick „user is allowed to administer the computer“
- logout
- Login with the standard user account (which now has admin rights)
- optionally: remove the admin account

Comment: It goes without saying the last point is "optionally: remove the admin account *that has none of your data*" **not** to remove the old standard account that you just made admin...